# How to modify the symbol for items in an “itemize” environment (dots, not triangles)

Tags: beamer, symbols, itemize

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
\end{itemized}
```

I am getting

[image]

What I want is dots instead of triangles in an `itemize` environment.

Comment: Is the second `itemized` a typo? (should be `itemize`?)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{rounded}% _or_ as an alternative:
%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]% see comment

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hello World!
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Hello inner World!
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Hello inner inner World!
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This change also enumerate list, `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]` only change itemize lists.

Comment: Yes, but then everything else is _not_ "rounded"

Comment: That's what I said :)

Comment: that's right :-)

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you issue the instruction

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\textbullet}
```

in the preamble.

Do please consult section 16.3.3, "Setting Beamer's Templates", of the user guide of the `beamer` package for more information.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\textbullet}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello World!
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark: The code provided above modifies the symbol that's shown for level-1 items. For items in level-2 and level-3 itemized lists, use `\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{...}` and `\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{...}`, respectively. (Aside: Your audience will very much appreciate if your beamer document doesn't feature 3 nested itemized lists...)